# How to save NSArray to xml

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I have NSArray with structure:

```
(
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>",
    "<timeline>",
    "<block id = 1/>",
    "<block id = 001/>",
    "<block id = 002/>",
    "<block id = 003/>",
    "<block id = 004/>",
    "<block id = 005/>",
    "<block id = 006/>",
    "<block id = 007/>",
    "<block id = 008/>",
    "<block id = 009/>",
    "<block id = 010/>",
    "<block id = 011/>",
    "<block id = 012/>",
    "</timeline>"
)
```

I want to save it into xml. I try `[arrayWithXmlData writeToFile:filePathDocArray atomically:YES];`

But when I open file I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;</string>
    <string>&lt;timeline</string>
    <string>&lt;block id = 1/&gt;</string>
    <string>&lt;block id = 001/&gt;</string>
    <string>&lt;block id = 002/&gt;</string>
    <string>&lt;block id = 003/&gt;</string>
    <string>&lt;block id = 004/&gt;</string>
    <string>&lt;block id = 005/&gt;</string>
    <string>&lt;block id = 006/&gt;</string>
    <string>&lt;block id = 007/&gt;</string>
    <string>&lt;block id = 008/&gt;</string>
    <string>&lt;block id = 009/&gt;</string>
    <string>&lt;block id = 010/&gt;</string>
    <string>&lt;block id = 011/&gt;</string>
    <string>&lt;block id = 012/&gt;</string>
    <string>&gt;timeline&gt;</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

How I can save this format into xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <timeline>
 <block id="0"/>
 <block id="2/>
 <block id="3/>
 </timeline>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)**
One solutions is to append the strings in the array to a single string and write it to file using encoding like:

```
NSString *strToWrite = [arrayWithXmlData componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];   
[strToWrite writeToFile:filePathDocArray atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

2)
Another solution is to write the strings to file using a loop. You can use the file append mode and apply formatting also.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your id's, not the xml strings. You already have the xml stored in your array. If you want to save that as xml, all you have to do is write each line to a file.

Comment: I try it before     `NSString *str=  [arrayWithXmlData componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    
    [str writeToFile:filePathDocArray
          atomically:NO
            encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
               error:nil];` But it will be in one row. And it is bad idea to parse this.

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
NSString *string = [arrayWithXmlData componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">\"" withString:@">"];
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<\"" withString:@"<"];
[string writeToFile:filePathDocArray atomically:YES];
```